# Can you do $array["string"] in C#

Tags: c#, php, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set array key as string not int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231318/set-array-key-as-string-not-int)

I know you can do something like 
`$array["string"]`  in php but can you also do something like this in C# instead of using arrays with numbers?

Comment: That's generally called an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays in PHP are in reality more like dictionaries in C#. So yes, you can do this, using a [**`Dictionary<string, YourValueType>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict["hello"] = 42;
dict["world"] = 12;
```

Comment: Of course the "YourValueType" doesn't really need to be a ValueType.

Comment: Be aware the above code will throw an exception because the items have not been added to the dictionary

Comment: @Ben No, the code works as-is.

Comment: You are right, I have been using dictionaries since they cam out in c# 2.0 and i had no idea you could add dictionary items in that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store key/value pairs, you could probably use a Dictionary:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

In PHP the "array" class is actually a map, which is a data structure that maps values to keys.

In C# there are a [lot of distinct data structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336800) classes. Each with it's own characteristics.
Wikipedia is a good starting point to read about basic data structures in general:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure#Common_data_structures

Answer (score 0):

`var ar = new string[]{"one", "two"};`

Comment: i mean array["string"]="blah blah" instead of array[1]="blah blah";

Comment: That's an array of strings, not an associative array with string keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dictionary` for this purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary["key"] = "value";
```

and so on