# Converting an array from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to convert the below shown PHP array to a C# array.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Please help me to port this.

```
<?php
$var["figures"]["en"] = array(
    array(
        "table"    => "Revenue",
        "box"      => "Revenue",
        "axis"     => "Revenue",
        "legend"   => "Revenue",
        "link"     => "",
        "target"   => "",
        "footnote" => "",
        "unit"     => '',
        "stacked"  => '',
        "icon"     => ""
    ),
    array(
        "table"    => "PBIT",
        "box"      => "PBIT",
        "axis"     => "PBIT",
        "legend"   => "PBIT",
        "link"     => "",
        "target"   => "",
        "footnote" => "",
        "unit"     => '',
        "stacked"  => '',
        "icon"     => ""
    )
);
print_r($var);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support array's with string indexes. A [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is the closest you can get.

For a good example, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231318/set-array-key-as-string-not-int).