# What is this technique called in C#?

Tags: c#

I wanna define an object within some property, but I don't know how to do that. Like this:

```
var obj = ...;
obj["prop1"] = "Property 1";
obj["prop2"] = "Property 2";
```

And I can create a string to get one of them:

```
string temp = "prop1";
string prop1 = obj[temp];
```

Is it possible in C#?

Comment: It's called a dictionary in C#.

Comment: @Adrian no I think OP means indexers

Comment: [Indexer Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is a dictionary:

```
var obj = new Dictionary<string, string>();

obj.Add("prop1", "Property1");

Console.WriteLine(obj["prop1"]);
```

If the properties are well defined, I would recommend creating a class:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Prop1;
    public string Prop2;
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
var obj = new MyObject
{
    Prop1 = "Property 1",
    Prop2 = "Property 2"
};

Console.WriteLine(obj.Prop1); //Will echo out 'Property 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string,string> obj = new Dictionary<string,string>();
obj.Add("prop1","Property 1");
obj.Add("prop2","Property 2");

string temp = obj["prop1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called an indexer. You can add an indexer to classes. It usually takes 1 or more arguments.

Calling an indexer:

To call an indexer, you use an instance of that class and add `[]` at the end of the name. Then, add the arguments into the `[]`. Let's take string as an example. In the string class, there is an indexer that takes a argument of type `int`. It gets the character at that index of the string.

```
char theFirstChar = someString[0];
```

The indexer can also take multiple arguments:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[10, 10]; //Note: This is not an indexer
int someValue = matrix[9, 4]; //This is
```

Syntax:

You define an indexer like this: (I used the string example)

```
public char this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        // code
    }
    set
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

It's very much like a property.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you get in C# is [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Source: [Set array key as string not int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231318/set-array-key-as-string-not-int)

Answer (score 0):

It's called ExpandoObject in C#

see https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20expandoobject