# c# Convert First Values To Keys

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an `Array` sample:

```
string[] arr = new string[5];
arr[0] = "a";
arr[1] = "b";
arr[2] = "c";
arr[3] = "d";
```

And I want to do this:

```
arr["a"] = "b";
arr["c"] = "d";
```

This is my code and it didn't solve my problem:

```
for (int i =0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (i + 1 < str.Length)
    {
        string key = str[i];
        arr[key] = str[i + 1];
        MessageBox.Show(key);

    }

}
```

Comment: no that second set of code wouldnt because it would create an arr["b"] ="c" .. you need to do every other number... what do you think you would change to do that?

Comment: thx @bugDinder To reply , You are right but I can not find the solution I asked the question to find the solution

Comment: Maybe you should learn what is an array before and after that you should decide if that structure is correct for your needs and not choose the data structure and ask later if is correct for your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set array key as string not int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231318/set-array-key-as-string-not-int)

Comment: You can have a look at the Dictionary, if keys are unique

Comment: what is the value of `str` ?

Comment: str is string and split it to get array

Comment: @MidoBona and what you want to show?

Comment: i want show first value to key and second to value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *dictionary* (when given a *key*, e.g. `"a"`, `"b"` you want to have the corresponding value `"c"` or `"d"`). *Linq* solution:

```
  string[] arr = new string[5];
  arr[0] = "a";
  arr[1] = "b";
  arr[2] = "c";
  arr[3] = "d";

  Dictionary<string, string> dict = Enumerable
    .Range(0, arr.Length / 2)
    .ToDictionary(i => arr[2 * i], i => arr[2 * i + 1]);
```

Test

```
 string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dict
   .Select(pair => $"arr[\"{pair.Key}\"] = \"{pair.Value}\";"));

 Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
 arr["a"] = "b";
 arr["c"] = "d";
```

Comment: I get this error Additional information: An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: @Mido Bona: what is your *actual data*? You are supposed to get such an error if you have *key conflict*, e.g. `arr = ["a", "a", "b", "c"]` - what is the expected result - `dict["a"] == "b"` or `dict["a"] == "c"`?

Comment: arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Comment: @Mido Bona: I've run my code and it returns the outcome I provided; I've changed the input into `string[] arr = new string[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}` and I've got the same outcome.

Comment: @Mido Bona: you are, probably, doing something like `arr = new string[10]; arr[0] = "a"; arr[1] = "b"; arr[2] = "c"; arr[3] = "d";` - the array has `10` items, but only first `4` of them are keys and values. Is it your case?

Comment: arr = new string[4]; arr[0] = "a"; arr[1] = "b"; arr[2] = "c"; arr[3] = "d";

Comment: In fact I am contacting api And get results other than in the example but there are some empty values Do you want to see the ِArray ?

Comment: @Mido Bona: yes, and, please, specify what do you want to do with empty values (what is the *desired outcome*)

Comment: Empty Values Can Be Not Empty "id","*1","customer","admin","actual-profile","a","username","n7kv5z","password","qngdxk","shared-users","1","wireless-psk","","wireless-enc-key","","wireless-enc-algo","none","uptime-used","7h13m53s","download-used","252818743","upload-used","29738854","last-seen","jun/17/2017 14:37:49","active","false","incomplete","false","disabled","false"

Comment: First Values Impossible Empty

Comment: Can You Help Me ?

Comment: @Mido Bona: I see! **My bad**; I've edited the answer; Sorry for my misunderstanding: we should treat even items (zero-based: 0, 2, 4...) as keys add odd ones (1, 3, 5...) as values

Comment: @Mido Bona: please, try my edit it should start working now

Comment: @Mido Bona: `string myId = dict["id"];` or `string myId; if (dict.TryGetValue("id", out myId)) {/*we have an "id" and its value is in myId*/} else {/* no "id" in the dictionary */}`

Answer (score 1):

The indexer in c# is always an `int`. You have to use a different data structure if you want to use a string as index. For example use Dictionary

```
var arr = new Dictionary<string, string>();
arr[key] = str[i + 1];
```

Comment: I have This Code Put arr["b"] = "c"; Not Solve It

Comment: you cannot use the code  arr["b"] = "c"; on an array. it's just not how the language c# works

Comment: When get All Values arr["b"] Show !

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
OrderedDictionary
```

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx)

here is reposted example:

```
    // The following code example enumerates the elements of a OrderedDictionary.
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class OrderedDictionarySample
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        // Creates and initializes a OrderedDictionary.
        OrderedDictionary myOrderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey1", "testValue1");
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey2", "testValue2");
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("keyToDelete", "valueToDelete");
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("testKey3", "testValue3");

        ICollection keyCollection = myOrderedDictionary.Keys;
        ICollection valueCollection = myOrderedDictionary.Values;

        // Display the contents using the key and value collections
        DisplayContents(keyCollection, valueCollection, myOrderedDictionary.Count);

        // Modifying the OrderedDictionary
        if (!myOrderedDictionary.IsReadOnly)
        {
            // Insert a new key to the beginning of the OrderedDictionary
            myOrderedDictionary.Insert(0, "insertedKey1", "insertedValue1");

            // Modify the value of the entry with the key "testKey2"
            myOrderedDictionary["testKey2"] = "modifiedValue";

            // Remove the last entry from the OrderedDictionary: "testKey3"
            myOrderedDictionary.RemoveAt(myOrderedDictionary.Count - 1);

            // Remove the "keyToDelete" entry, if it exists
            if (myOrderedDictionary.Contains("keyToDelete"))
            {
                myOrderedDictionary.Remove("keyToDelete");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}Displaying the entries of a modified OrderedDictionary.",
            Environment.NewLine);
        DisplayContents(keyCollection, valueCollection, myOrderedDictionary.Count);

        // Clear the OrderedDictionary and add new values
        myOrderedDictionary.Clear();
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("newKey1", "newValue1");
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("newKey2", "newValue2");
        myOrderedDictionary.Add("newKey3", "newValue3");

        // Display the contents of the "new" Dictionary using an enumerator
        IDictionaryEnumerator myEnumerator =
            myOrderedDictionary.GetEnumerator();

        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}Displaying the entries of a \"new\" OrderedDictionary.",
            Environment.NewLine);

        DisplayEnumerator(myEnumerator);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Displays the contents of the OrderedDictionary from its keys and values
    public static void DisplayContents(
        ICollection keyCollection, ICollection valueCollection, int dictionarySize)
    {
        String[] myKeys = new String[dictionarySize];
        String[] myValues = new String[dictionarySize];
        keyCollection.CopyTo(myKeys, 0);
        valueCollection.CopyTo(myValues, 0);

        // Displays the contents of the OrderedDictionary
        Console.WriteLine("   INDEX KEY                       VALUE");
        for (int i = 0; i < dictionarySize; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0,-5} {1,-25} {2}",
                i, myKeys[i], myValues[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // Displays the contents of the OrderedDictionary using its enumerator
    public static void DisplayEnumerator(IDictionaryEnumerator myEnumerator)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   KEY                       VALUE");
        while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   {0,-25} {1}",
                myEnumerator.Key, myEnumerator.Value);
        }
    }
}

/*
This code produces the following output.

   INDEX KEY                       VALUE
   0     testKey1                  testValue1
   1     testKey2                  testValue2
   2     keyToDelete               valueToDelete
   3     testKey3                  testValue3


Displaying the entries of a modified OrderedDictionary.
   INDEX KEY                       VALUE
   0     insertedKey1              insertedValue1
   1     testKey1                  testValue1
   2     testKey2                  modifiedValue


Displaying the entries of a "new" OrderedDictionary.
   KEY                       VALUE
   newKey1                   newValue1
   newKey2                   newValue2
   newKey3                   newValue3

*/
```

Comment: sorry this solution not solve my problem Because I do not add value manually

Comment: this is an example how to use ordereddictionary, you do not have to use to do it manualy. You can put inserts into array. We wont write you an exact code because we do not really know what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @MidoBona in your question you add the value manually: arr[key] = str[i + 1];

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i += 2)
{
    dict.Add(arr[i], arr[i + 1])
}
```

One thing to watch with this, is that the keys will need to be unique, so you'll want to add some error handling to catch duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean? This will result in dict["a"] == "b" and dict["c"] == "d"

You cannot access your array by a string indexer, you'll need to use a dictionary, and this will give you the result you need